# Update a writable store using a function that depends on another store

Tags: svelte

a page of my site contains a sort of carousel so some slides that user can navigate.
Imagine 5 slides and two buttons (`previous` and `next`) to change the current slide.

So I created a `slides` store containing an array of 5 objects and another state `slideIndex` that is the index of the current slide:

```
const slides = readable([{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}])
const slideIndex = writable(0)
```

then I need two functions that update the index and these functions will be called by a component:

```
function nextSlide() {
  slideIndex.update((slideIndex) => {
    const isLast = slides.length - 1 === slideIndex
    const nextIndex = isLast ? 0 : slideIndex + 1
    slideIndex = nextIndex
    return slideIndex
  })
}

function previousSlide() {
  slideIndex.update((slideIndex) => {
    const isFirst = slideIndex === 0
    const previousIndex = isFirst ? slides.length - 1 : slideIndex - 1
    slideIndex = previousIndex
    return slideIndex
  })
}

const currentSlide = derived(
  [slides, slideIndex],
  ([$slides, $slideIndex]) => {
    return $slides.slides[$slideIndex]
  }
)
```

the logic seems correct to me but I get an error inside `nextSlide` and `previousSlide` when try to get the lenght of `slide` (line `const isLast = slides.length - 1 === slideIndex`):

```
Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Readable<{}[]>'
```

I think a need a sort of `derived` that can update a `writable` store. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just as the error text said, length property is not applicable to the variable *slides* which is an instance of Readable store.

Length property exists for instances of Iterables (in this context is List), which is the value stored in the Readable instance. We are trying to access this.

In order to access the stored value, you need to do one of the followings

*IF you write your codes in between script tag* in .svelte file, use **$slides.length**,

Or,

*IF you are writing in .ts or .js file,*
**use get function** from svelte/store

```
import {get} from 'svelte/store'

function nextSlide() {
          slideIndex.update((slideIndex) => {
            let slideLength = get(slides).length;
            const isLast = slidesLength - 1 === slideIndex;
            const nextIndex = isLast ? 0 : slideIndex + 1;
            slideIndex = nextIndex;
            unsubscribe();
            return slideIndex;
          });
        }
```

And the same for previousSlides() function

Hope it helps!

*NOTE*: If you are using Svelte 5, try to explore **Rune**.